# Maya python back slash replacing issue

Tags: python, filepath, maya

I am Trying to add a custom path filed in my GUI but the problem is that when i use the command

```
cmds.fileDialog2(filemode=3,dialogStyle =1)
```

i get a file path like

```
C:\Users\anoorani\Desktop\Test
```

However Maya only seems to be reading paths like

```
C:/Users/anoorani/Desktop/Test
```

The backticks seem to be a problem
is there a way to replace "\"  with "/"  in python maya.....?

Comment: `os.path.normpath(filePath)` has worked for me so far...

Comment: you maybe can do `out.replace('\\', '/')`

Comment: @ArgiriKotsaris: I think you should post that as an answer. Just add a link and explain what it does, and there's not much more to say.

Comment: It's good practice to always swap your paths to forward slashes , even on windows, since Windows works with forward slashes and backslashes are typo magnets.

Comment: Thankyou so much!!!!@ Argiri Kotsaris the os.path.normpath  worked for me!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Acording to @ArgiriKotsaris note, you can use [os.path.normpath(path)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath):

> Normalize a pathname by collapsing redundant separators and up-level references.
>
> So that A//B, A/B/, A/./B and A/foo/../B all become A/B.
>
> This string manipulation may change the meaning of a path that contains symbolic links.
>
> On Windows, it converts forward slashes to backward slashes.

So your code be:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import os

path = cmds.fileDialog2(fm=3,dialogStyle =1)
path = path and os.path.normpath(path[0])
```

Or if you want to always using forward slashes, then no needs to `os` module and change last line to:

```
path = path and path[0].replace('\\', '/')
```

Note that name of file mode argument for [fileDialog2](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2013/en_us/CommandsPython/fileDialog2.html) is `fileMode` or `fm` and not `filemode`.

Also `fileDialog2` return a list of paths or None.

Comment: normpath always converts to the appropriate format for the local filesystem. If you want forward slashes every time, you need to normpath (to get all the cleanup benefits) then replace `\\ ` with `/`.

Comment: I'd personally go for `path and os.path.normpath(path[0]).replace('\\', '/')` as it keeps the benefits of normpath (like collapsing redundant separators) and guarantees forward-slashes. I'm curious if anyone has a better method...

Comment: If using fileDialog2, what benefit is there to running normpath before replace, especially on windows?